# Prevent Bad Answers from Reducing Attractivity of a Question in the Browse List of Newest Questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, question-lists

When potential answerers browse the list of newest questions (concerning their fields of interest), questions without any answer typically appear more attractive because often the first answerer can get the merits, given a decent answer.  For an asker this means that getting a *bad* answer is a disadvantage because the bad answer might prevent better answers from being given, just because the question appears less attractive.

I deem this effect unwanted.

To prevent this, I propose to change the way the number of answers is displayed in the browser of the newest questions.  If all answers have a vote below zero (are considered bad), the question should still appear attractive for answerers, e. g. by greying out the number of answers or by putting it into parentheses, thus marking the question as "still attractive".

This is ***not*** the same as the feature of the list of "unanswered questions"!  (My [former question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256446/mark-a-question-with-only-bad-answers-as-unanswered-in-the-normal-browsing-list) has been wrongly marked as a duplicate concerning this feature.)  The list of unanswered questions is meant for potential *answerers* while the feature I'm asking for is supposed to benefit the *askers* by publicly showing that their questions are still wide open and answers still welcome.  Also, the list of unanswered questions sorts by upvotes, not by time, so it is not possible (AFAIK) the see the newest unanswered questions, and we all know that potential answerers will find newer questions more attractive than old ones.