# A mark to indicate that I, the asker, am not satisfied with an answer

Tags: feature-request, answers

**User stories**:

As a user who posts a question, I would like to have the ability to show that one or many answers to my question was not satisfactory to me, and that I would welcome other users to add additional answers to my question.

As a user who answers questions, I would like to have the ability to see when a user has received a reply, but who is not yet satisfied with it.

For the sake of both these two parties. I think it would be beneficial for the user to be able to mark an answer, instead of just rating or commenting on it. I.e displaying it in another color, or somehow making it stand out. It would be beneficial for both these two types of users.

Downvoting an answer would not show up in the listing page, nor would commenting that it is not useful either. What would be good is a way to see that a question that has received one or many answers, that the OP is still actively looking for an answer. Right now the only way to determine that is by looking at the OP's rep.

Comment: This is already covered by bounties, voting, and commenting.

Comment: If you're not satisfied with an answer, you can downvote and/or leave a comment to explain why you're not satisfied.  To show you're still looking for other answers, don't accept one, and edit your question to specify what you're still looking for.  A simple "unsatisfactory" mark, without a way to specify _why_, would not be particularly useful.

Comment: No it isn't. Downvoting an answer won't show up in the listing, and most low rep users won't even be able to down vote without losing rep themselves. Commenting doesn't show up in the listing page either. You would have to click on it to find out.

Comment: Enough people have qualms about casting anonymous downvotes that it's hard for me to believe that a "your attempt to help me didn't help" sign, credited by design to the asker, would gain much traction. I understand the impetus for the suggestion, however.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: You do realize that for low rep users, casting downvotes cost rep? Even the most ridiculous questions have +1, and sometimes a valid question has -1

Comment: Downvotes cost rep no matter how much rep a user has.  Ideally, you earn that rep back too, when the answer is either deleted for quality issues or edited for correctness at which point you can change your vote.

Comment: Saying "I don't want to use the tools made available to me because I don't want to temporarily lose the occasional point" is not useful.

Comment: @davidism: No it doesn't. I have 3000 rep and I can downvote a bit without losing rep.

Comment: No, you still loose rep, however what you properly intend to say is that since you have 3k rep losing 1 or 2 (or possibly more) doesn't matter to you. (You don't loose rep for down voting questions, you do however on Answers)

Comment: The qualms I've seen expressed are of the "makes people feel bad" variety. Yes, I feel the psychological difference of downvoting and losing that point on sites where I've got much lower rep than here.

Comment: Downvoting an answer always costs the voter 1 rep point, regardless of the voter. Downvoting a question never costs the voter, regardless of the voter. No votes on Meta.SO either cost or grant rep.

Comment: Dude, Down votes on Meta are an' indication of that people disagree / doni't think the feature is needed / useful.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: No, I don't downvote often. But when I do, I don't lose rep

Comment: @Epodax: Ok, so then tell me why it's not useful. Maybe you just ignore low rep users instead?

Comment: If you're downvoting _answers_, not questions, on Stack Overflow, not Meta, and you're not losing reputation, then please file a bug report.

Comment: I'm really unclear about what problem you seem to have about / think there is for low rep users.

Comment: I don't find your feature useful / needed because I believe it isn't a high enough issue to warrant the time and resources needed to develop this, further more I believe it would have a more negative impact than a positive one because some (or many) will feel that the "No useful answer found" is hurtful (_"So, my answer isn't good enough for you?!"_ - Which then might lead to _"FINE! Then I just won't ANSWER!"_) - Which will then defeat the purpose of SO.

Comment: @davidism: The problem is, as stated in my "feature", is that I have no way of knowing from the listing page whether the user has actually been helped by the answer(s) he or she has been getting.

Comment: @Epodax: Well the time for me to having to click on a question to already have found out it has been correctly answered is already time consuming. Some low rep users can't accept an answer in a certain time frame for example. So it would save everyone a lot of time. Also help out the OP who doesn't get help because nobody wants to bother with a low rep user with 2 answers.

Comment: But you do, as I explained in my answer: if they accepted an answer the count is highlighted green.  If it's not, then stop worrying about the op so much and worry more about the question.  Your complaint seems to be "I won't know whether to answer the question until I look at it", which is exactly what you should be doing.

Comment: Unless you have a rubbish internet connection checking if a question has a answer shouldn't take you more than 2-3 Seconds, 5 MAX.

Comment: @davidism: Yeah obviously, when it's green that's final. But many times it's not green because the user hasn't bother to accept it, or he or she has to wait a certain time because they can do so.

Comment: @Epodax: It has nothing to do with internet connection. I have to read the answers, and possibly the question as well.

Comment: The "users don't accept answers" discussion has been done to death. If that's your real complaint, it's a duplicate and the answer is "move on".  Again, you should be considering the quality of the question and existing answers when deciding to answer, not about the behavior of the op.

Comment: @davidism: Yeah you already said that. And no, again, that's not my complaint. What if I was a user who had 3 replies, but none was right? Most people wouldn't click on it thinking it was a user who just doesn't accept or reply to comment questions. There are so may SO users who do that

Comment: @dan-klasson also, side note on the downvotes you're getting here. On a Feature Request, votes are for "I think this should be implemented" and "I don't think this should be implemented" in ADDITION to their normal meaning. The fact you got 0 up, 11 down, means that out of the 32 views you have on this question, 11 people decided this was NOT needed, and none thought this would be. It doesn't necessarily speak to your phrasing or anything.

Comment: Then you would add a bounty, making it visible on the bounty tab.  Or you would edit the question to clarify what you are looking for, making it visible on the active tab.  Despite your insistence that "many users behave this way", you present no evidence to back that up.  Additionally, you should understand that SO is not meant for the immediate gratification of the op.  If good answers take a while to show up, so be it.

Comment: Opinion is not a good motivation for a feature request, data is.  See [shog9's explanation of how to make a good feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/400617).  I would also advise that you not stoop to insulting users, especially since many of the users on meta are the most active users on main.

Comment: This question appears to be a possible dup of either https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306513/mark-the-answer-as-reviewed-but-asker-still-looking-for-the-answer or https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256472/prevent-bad-answers-from-reducing-attractivity-of-a-question-in-the-browse-list

Comment: @dan-klasson I posed a similar proposal, linked in the comment just above. Didn't attract that much attention as this one. I should be thankful for that, I guess. High-reps believe bounties take care of the issue completely, and that waiting 2 days is perfectly normal and acceptable. But if that is true then there would be no issue. Who are we to say that there in fact is one?

Comment: @Dialecticus I'm slightly triggered (disclaimer: I'm not "triggered") by the "acceptable" part of your text, you seem to have an' idea that you are "owed" a fast reply or at least within 2 days, you are not. People here on SO answer out of their own free time and will, and demanding that people answer faster is just ungrateful.

Comment: No one would be demanding anything. The proposal woild be just one more tool that would benefit both askers and answerers. It's a win-win solution.

Comment: @Dialecticus: Good to see someone sees the benefit. Also, low rep users can't create bounties. Personally I want this because having to click on each question to see if the replies were helpful or not. Most of the time I don't bother and just skip unaccepted questions that have one or several answers.

Comment: @Dialecticus My apologies, seem like I misunderstood your comment then :)

Answer (score 22):

All of this is already covered by existing features or actions you can take.

Show that an answer is not satisfactory: don't accept, possibly downvote, leave a comment explaining why it didn't help.  The cost of a downvote will be reimbursed when the answer is deleted for quality issues, or you can undo your vote once it is edited for correctness.

Want additional answers: add a bounty which adds it to the bounty tab, or edit the question to clarify what you're asking which bumps it on the active tab.

See when a user is not yet satisfied: questions with an accepted answer highlight the answer count with a green box, look for questions without it.

---

Based on these comment threads, however, it seems like you're just not sure how to evaluate what questions to answer.

You should not evaluate which questions to answer based on any of the following: number of answers, whether an answer is accepted, reputation of op, continued presence of op.

You should answer questions which are well asked and which you feel have not been answered satisfactorily.  Yes, this requires more effort on your part, but that effort to evaluate the quality of existing posts is what makes Stack Overflow a valuable resource.

Comment: Yes but there are so many users, especially with low reputation, that don't accept valid answers. Downvoting an answer does not show up in the listing page.

Comment: The "users don't accept answers" discussion has been done to death.  If that's your real complaint, it's a duplicate and the answer is "move on".

Comment: If you want to see information such as comment count or answers < 0 count, the Stack Exchange API is well documented.  Users frequently write scripts on http://stackapps.com/ to add extra functions to the site.

Comment: That's not my complaint. I am talking about many posters are new, some of them post and never get back to you, while others are keen to get help. And right now, there is really no way to differentiate between them. The only way we have is by ignoring low rep users.

Comment: Worrying about the op at all (beyond deciding that they've asked a good question), is missing the point of Stack Overflow.  They are simply one user in a target audience of millions.  Write good answers to good questions.  Upvotes from the community are more important than accepts from the single op.

Comment: I'm both the OP and the person who answers. I am just trying to add a feature request.

Comment: If your answer is THAT good, you'll get upvotes, no matter what the OP has done. If that is an on-topic SO question, that is. People visit good on topic questions, and upvote answers on the merit of the answer. Even if the OP has his solution, wouldn't you want to make the Internet a better place by posting a good, be-all end-all answer when you can?

Comment: @Patrice: I am not talking about good topic questions. Most questions are simple, or even stupid. It doesn't mean we should not try to help them when others have failed.

Comment: @dan-klasson actually... it does. Stack is all about quality questions, for the NEXT user with the same problem. I don't think we should answer bad questions (some users even downvote good answers on bad questions. I don't go that far, but I can still understand that sentiment). It's commendable you want to help everyone, but not very realistic or scalable to a site the size of Stack.

Comment: @Patrice: Well, at least the people who want to help, would at least know if the answers to the question were unsatisfactory or not. Sometimes even a +1 can be a shitty question, and a -1 can be fairly OK. At least that is my experience.

Comment: @dan-klasson but again, you focus too much on the guy posting his question. Realize that the best questions on stack are those that were seen by THOUSANDS of people who went "omg that was useful!" For THOSE visitors, a better answer is ALWAYS beneficial. Also note in my comment I didn't talk about the actual score of the question, only its quality. Yes some people vote in weird ways (or Tim REALLY needs to get ahold of his keys...), but that's another discussion

Comment: @dan-klasson if the op is too lazy to mark an answer as accepted, what makes you think they'll mark another one as not acceptable or not satisfactory?

Comment: @dan-klasson this is part of making a feature request. The feature HAS to be hit on all sides to make sure it holds water. If it doesn't hold water, it likely won't get implemented. This is a normal, healthy process for deciding if a feature is worth having or not. There has to be a damn good reason for a feature request to go past being a feature request.

Comment: Kevin B has it exactly right, the argument that "Users don't mark answers accepted, so we need a way to say they aren't satisfied" is fallacious. If a user doesn't know enough to check the green check mark, what makes you think they will know to hit the red X (or whatever we use for this feature)?

Comment: @dan-klasson Stop insulting people on meta, PLEASE. In any case, you realize that answering a question viewed and appreciated by THOUSANDS helps a lot more than ONE OP, whose question will not be searched? If you truly want to help, use Pareto. Put 20% of the effort where it'll have 80% of the effect

Comment: @KevinB: Because when the answer is already given to them, they would have less incentive to make that effort. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: @dan-klasson So because people care more about *the entire rest of the world* than just the one person asking the question means that they don't want to help people?  Sorry, but no.  You're being told that what you're trying to do *isn't actually as effective a means of helping people*.  Yes, helping just one person that you build a personal relationship with and that can pat you on the back might make you feel better than writing a quality answer to a generalized question that helps tens of thousands of people with a problem they couldn't solve, but the latter is actually *more helpful*.

Comment: @Patrice: Right, definitely. It will help more people for sure. But what about that person who is struggling and who wants to find a solution ASAP? That's not very beneficial for him or her. You work for Google? And all your answers are about Google products. Could it be that you get paid to answer "good" questions on SO perhaps?

Comment: @Servy: Perhaps, but some people like to do different things. We are not all alike. And we are all on a journey to become better at what we do. And perhaps we go about it in different ways along that journey.

Comment: @dan-klasson I won't even answer that part of your comment, as I sincerely find it a bit insulting that you infer intentions to me like that (plus it's ENTIRELY irrelevant here, so it's just an ad hominem point). In any case, Stack was never meant for the guy who wants a solution ASAP. It was meant for long lasting Q&As. If OP wants a solution NAO... he can hire a consultant, hit a chat room, go on a discussion board that doesn't care for quality? Stack became the success it is because it's so hellbent on quality.

Comment: @dan-klasson  You're the one who's trying to assert that the people on meta don't want to help people and you do.  I'm not saying that you aren't trying to help people (just that you could do a better job of helping people by adjusting your perspective).

Comment: Why the hail would it be a bad thing for Patrice to answer questions about the product he's paid to work on, @dan-klasson? It would be freaking _awesome_ if SO had more vendors [providing concise, useful solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32588335/603977) to problems with their products.

Comment: @JoshCaswell one thing man... I'm French. Patrice is a male name :) (thanks for the support though :P)

Comment: Noted and corrected, @Patrice, sorry.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I get this at least three times a week, no worries. I would rename myself to Patrick here if I really cared that much :P

Comment: @dan-klasson again with the assumption of what people are thinking and doing.  You do not know why anyone behaves the way they do (besides yourself).  Unless you have real data demonstrating why your feature would be beneficial, please refrain from further generalizations without evidence.

Comment: All right, I missed your point there, @dan-klasson, but now that I understand it I don't know why it's relevant. Even if Patrice's assignment at work is to answer questions on SO, he faces the same problem of finding questions to answer as someone who does it for any other reason.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: We all do. Everyday I find answers to my problems on SO. Yet sometimes some of us find it in our hearts to help others out who used to be just as clueless as we once were. I just wish that Patrice, would spend as much time as he does on META doing that. But hey, we are all different.

Comment: @dan-klasson why do you think he doesn't?  I feel like this line of discussion is not helping further your actual feature request.

Comment: @dan-klasson seriously, why is this suddenly turning into an ad hominem attack about me? You say that "users on meta are all like that" do notice I never attacked anyone, I just explained how stack works and how little your Feature Request would change that. YOU are the one constantly attacking people.... In this debate, even though you started it, you seem so far the most toxic participant

Comment: As for my motivation for Meta : I like the site, I like the community, I think that the site can evolve, has issues that can be solved, and I'd like to be a part of that. I may spend a lot of time on the meta site, but I do believe that new users of SO need help to learn the site as much as new coders need help understanding code

Answer (score 13):

**There's answers, but I'm not satisfied with them:**

[image]

**There's answers, and I'm satisfied with one of them:**

[image]

What you're asking for can already be seen. If an answer is not accepted, odds are that it's not what question's OP is looking for.

Comment: Read my post again please. It's written in simple English. Sometimes you have 0 votes and 3 answers which none have been accepted yet. How do you know if it is a user who hasn't bothered to accept, or simply one that's looking for another answer? You either have to look at the rep or click and read it.

Comment: @dan-klasson Read [How to make a good feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta/272617#272617) It's written in simple English too. If you won't even bother in reading what the question is about or how it has been formulated, why would you want to see the information you're requesting on question listing? Either way, you have to click the question if you really want to know details.

Comment: @dan-klasson using "there's an accepted answer" or even "there's already an answer" is not the right way to decide whether to answer a question.  Answer a question if it is a good question and if you feel that the existing answers are not satisfactory.  The behavior of the op should not factor in at all.

Comment: Additionally, looking at the rep of the op is a terrible metric.  How do you know if the op "can't be bothered to accept" or just hasn't been around (not everyone hangs out on SO 24/7 or even more than once a week), or isn't ready to accept but is still invested?  Again, it shouldn't matter, but you really need to re-think how you're evaluating questions.

Comment: WORD @davidism,  protecting low-rep users from rep-racism

Comment: @edrodriguez: Oh, I am sorry. I didn't quite find that page "how to make a good feature request", especially since the title of the "question" was "Can we talk about the voting culture here on Meta?". Not really FAQ material. Seriously, what's up with people like you on META?

Comment: @davidism: Exactly, how would I know? Or perhaps the OP is around and is patiently waiting for an answer, and has already commented on each answer. There is no way of knowing. Hence my feature request.

Comment: @dan-klasson my point is exactly that you don't know and shouldn't care.  The op's responsiveness should not be a factor in deciding which questions to answer.

Comment: @dan-klasson I wouldn't expect you to have seen that post by shog9, since I agree it's not obvious how to find it, but I had come across it again recently and it was relevant, so I pointed it out.

Comment: @dan-klasson please calm down, it seems like you've missed the point of what I said.  Your sentiment that you want to help others does not conflict with mine that you should not worry about whether the op is responsive.  A good answer to a good question will help many more people than just the op.

Comment: @davidism: I'm super calm. That's just the way I talk. And my feature request doesn't conflict with your UI experience on SO either.

Comment: @dan-klasson Stack Overflow is a site for professionals and enthusiasts.  While it is great to be passionate about your ideas, please keep that passion to a level that remains professional when speaking.

Comment: @dan-klasson when participating on meta, recognize that it is not the same dynamic as when participating on main.  Users participate on meta to discuss how the site works, so of course they care about fully understanding any feature requests that indicate that someone is not satisfied with how the site works.  However, they can only meaningfully discuss features requests that are well researched.  If they feel a request is unclear, they will discuss in order to clarify, and they will vote based on their agreement or disagreement.

Comment: @dan-klasson also recognize that active participants on meta are also active on main.  Their participation here does not effect their participation there, although the two may be positively correlated.

Comment: @dan-klasson I'm not sure what you're basing your idea that there is more participation on meta than main, but it's important to note that there are thousands of questions posted a day on main, while there are about ten per day on meta, so each post gets a bigger slice of everyone's attention.  I'm also not clear why you think I was "slamming" your idea, but I assure you I was responding in good faith that I felt that what you were asking for was already present and that if not you needed to clarify your request.

Comment: Helpful like the 650 answers that davidism has posted on SO (compared to 20 on Meta)? Or like the 3,000 answers that Servy has posted? Or what?

Comment: @JoshCaswell:  I am talking about all the comments, obviously.